# MySQL one-to-many, Java, hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

First...sorry for my description...I hope I can be clear.
I want to create a project, where I have cars and drivers. One car can have one driver and one driver can have many cars.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "carid")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "car_producator")
    private String producator;
    
    @Column(name = "car_model")
    private String model;
    
    @Column(name = "car_culoare")
    private String culoare;
    
    @Column(name = "car_esteInchiriata")
    private boolean esteInchiriata;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="driver_id")
    private Driver driver;
    
    private int car_soferID;
[...]
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "driver")
public class Driver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "driver_id")
    private int driver_id;
    
    @Column(name = "driver_name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "driver_license")
    private String license;
    
    @Column(name = "driver_phonenr")
    private String phoneNr;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "driver", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<Car> masini;

[...]
}
```

and this is the mysql syntax, which i don't understand very clear, if i have one to many relationships, do I need a 3rd table where i have id, carID and driverID for that car? sorry for my dummy questions

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `employee_directory`;
USE `employee_directory`;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `driver`;

CREATE TABLE `driver` (
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `driver_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `driver_license` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `driver_phonenr` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`driver_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `driver` VALUES 
    (1,'Tora1ie','Andrews','leslie@mail@com'),
    (2,'Tora2','Baumgarten','emma@mail@com'),
    (3,'Tora3i','Gupta','avani@mail@com'),
    (4,'Tora4','Petrov','yuri@mail@com'),
    (5,'Tora5','Vega','juan@mail@com');

create table `car` (
  `carid` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `driver_id` int unsigned not null,
  `car_producator` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `car_mode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `car_culoare` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    TINYINT
     `car_esteInchiriata` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  index car_driver_index(`driver_id`),
  foreign key (`driver_id`) references driver(`driver_id`) on delete cascade,
  primary key(`carid`)
);
```

Comment: yes you can use third table as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its completely upto you to decide as both the solution will work.

For the current code it will not create a third table but every row of Car table will have a driver value.

But it would be better if you make @ManyToMany as in future it will be easy for you even if the requirement changes and will have separate table.

Comment: Thank you Alien! I change the relation. I have a lot to learn.